# docker-compose secrets without swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I don't want to use docker secrets with swarm and I discovered that it's possible to do that.
Basically docker just mounts /run/secrets inside docker container, but when I enter the newly built docker container and do `echo $POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE` I get the path to my secret file.

```
root@94a0f092eeb1:/# echo $POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE
/run/secrets/db_password
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.4
        container_name: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: "db_user"
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
            POSTGRES_DB: "my_db"
        secrets:
          - db_password
        volumes:
            - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        expose:
            - 5432
secrets:
   db_password:
     file: ./POSTGRES_PASSWORD.txt
```

Is my password set correctly/ Is there something wrong with my file?

Comment: Hello! Not sure, what is the issue here? What do you expect from "echo $POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, so all I had to do is to remove

```
volumes:
    - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I'll try to figure out how to fix it, but essentially I answered my own question.

Here is a working example of `docker-compose.yml` file with secrets without using docker swarm:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.4
        container_name: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: "db_user"
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
            POSTGRES_DB: "my_db"
        secrets:
          - db_password
        ports:
            - "8888:5432"
secrets:
   db_password:
     file: ./POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

Comment: @stackoverflowed: From security perspective, not too secure. Just wanted to know if it's possible to do all of this without docker swarm

Comment: it also means that you can now push your docker-compose.yml in your git repo without your password in it

Comment: I'm interested in the concept.  It seems that the same could be accomplished through a `.env` file in .gitignore.  The more interesting question is how to share these secrets with your team.

Comment: In all the examples I have gone through never found a sample for secret file for multiple secrets key-value pair. Is this a possibility for multiple parameters in one secret file?

Comment: @JinnaBalu unless the image you’re using supports reading multiple parameters from one file / env variable, no.

Comment: It should support

Comment: This works but the local file has to have very broad permissions to ensure that the Postgres container user can read it. That defeats the purpose of making it secret.